# Are question about Vocaloid related to phonetics on topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm struggling to get [Maika](http://www.voctro-vocaloid.com/en/maika) to sing in latino american spanish, so I wonder whether there is a way to make the sound of **s** more like in spanish spoken in latino america, maybe combining different phonemes or changing the properties of the note.

The question is not entirely related to phonetics though, and I'd bet there are more people that could know the answer to that particular question here, than in the SE site dedicated to phonetics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see how this would be on topic. It sounds like a technical phonetics question, not a musical theory or practice question.

Although you suggest it won't get a good answer on a phonetics site, that is where you should post it.

Comment: I think I'll ask there then, thanks.